# How to ask someone about their French language proficiency?

Tags: formulation, questions

I'm looking forward to ask someone who studies French about their language proficiency. What are some common ways to ask this (i.e., How's your French? and such)?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Incidentally, I find it quite hard to answer about my French level to someone who hasn't seriously tried to learn another language. It's hard to express the difference between a highly proficient learner and a native speaker, because it consists not in understanding or making yourself understood, but in subtle choices between near-equivalents that instantly reveal your level to a native speaker... and the smaller the difference, the more revelatory... and it's hard to make someone understand that!

Answer (score 7):

> *Quel est ton niveau en français ?*

Informal:

> *C'est quoi ton niveau en français ?*
> *Tu te débrouilles comment en français ?*

Answer (score 1):

De nos jours on parle de **[maitrise](https://etab.ac-poitiers.fr/coll-menigoute/sites/coll-menigoute/IMG/pdf/l_evaluation_des_eleves.pdf)** (au moins dans le système éducatif) :

Très bonne maitrise, maitrise satisfaisante, maitrise insuffisante, d'où cette proposition :

> **Quelle est ta/votre maitrise du français/de la langue française ?**

On trouve une question similaire posée il y a 10 ans sur [WordReference](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/hows-your-french.2245419/) ;

Quelqu'un a proposé cette traduction littérale :

> Comment est ton français ?

Réponse d'un utilisateur :

> [ça] s'entend effectivement mais [ce] n'est à mon sens pas du tout correct.

En citant @jlliagre (merci !)

> "Quelle est ta maitrise du français ?" est compréhensible mais pas très idiomatique. "**Est-ce que tu maitrises le français ?**" est plus indiqué.

> De plus, "Comment est ton français ?" pourrait déclencher la réponse "Il est sympa, je te le présenterai bientôt" :-)

Comment: *Quelle est ta maitrise du français ?* is understandable but not very idiomatic. You might suggest instead  *Est-ce que tu maitrises le français ?* while *Comment est ton français ?* might trigger the answer *Il est sympa, je te le présenterai bientôt* ;-)